# Listdata.svc Error - Filter Option Not Working?

Tags: 2010, list-view

I am working in SP2010 and have a simple InfoPath form that calls the listdata.svc to populate a drop down. I am trying to work out the URL that will return me all of the State data from a list of 27K state data sets.

The atom/xml looks like this:

---

```
<entry m:etag="W/"1"">
    <id>http://blah.com/sites/S/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/US_Distance_Table(1)</id> 
  <title type="text">AL</title> 
- <content type="application/xml">
- <m:properties>
   <d:State>AL</d:State> 
   <d:City>ABBEVILLE</d:City> 
   <d:BandCode>100 Mile Band</d:BandCode> 
  </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

---

URL I am trying is:

---

http://Blah.com/sites/S/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/US_Distance_Table?$filter=State eq'TX'

---

But it returns error. Now peeling back the URL does return some results. For example, I can call ....listdata.svc/US_Distance_Table(5) and get the 5th record.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL looks right

But if your table has 27000 items, then you're probably hitting a resource throttling limit unless it's State is an indexed column